# Changing the folder icon's doesn't work on the desktop

Tags: icons

For some reason even though I have changed the folder icons on Ubuntu, they don't appear on the desktop.  Is their any fix I could do to get it to work, thanks

[image]

Comment: seems 0S is 20.04? Can you Confirm??

Comment: yes I am using 20.04 but I had the same problem yesterday when I was using 19.10